# PHP , read XML file sent via cURL

Tags: php, xml, url, curl, readxml

I have this code where I send data in an XML file via cURL to a press office. Now I want a feedback from the press that my orders are confirmed or done. I would like to have that in an XML file as well. I know how I send file via curl, now I would like to know how do i receive them so i can read out the data. Any suggestions are welcome.

this is how i send my XML:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $incomm_prod_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, str_replace('{voucher_code}', $voucher_code, $xml_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
```

So this is what i do on the ither side to get the XML:

> ```
>   $ch = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
>     $result_xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
> ```

But i get bool(false) as result back, so there is no xml sent?

EDIT: I can access the data like this:

> ```
>   if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){
>         $postText = file_get_contents('php://input');
>     }
>     die(var_dump($postText));
> ```

I edit one last time, maybe it will help others, i access now my xml this way:

```
            if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){
            $postText = file_get_contents('php://input');
        }
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($postText);
        $packing_number = $xml->xpath('/feedback/packing_number');
        $packing_status = $xml->xpath('/feedback/packing_status');
```

this will give you an array back, you can access it like:

> $packing_number[0]

or just loop trough it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the code you posted above doesn't *really* send the XML file.  All it does is place the content of that XML file into a `$_POST` variable attached to the request.

To receive data (on the other side), all you have to do is take a look into the `$_POST` variable and your XML data should be there.  You'd setup a script and data would be posted to it (possibly using the same method you are using above), and the content will be accessible to you.

Comment: hmm okay i do some more researches and i will give it a try, thank you

Comment: i try to do this on the other side:   `$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  $result_xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
  die(var_dump($result_xml));` but i get bool(false) back. Not sure how to access the xml there.

Comment: Why don't you update your post with that info... It's a little bit hard to read here in the comments...

Comment: may i ask one more thing. I can access now the xml, but only the values. I would like to have the full xml file. Like <tag>val</tag> not only the val.

Comment: They are still there - the problem is that your browser is thinking that the tags are HTML tags.   If you echo the contents into a `<pre>` or `<code>` tag, then you will see all of the data...